# LFS 6.7 /bin/sh Command not found

Tags: lfs

Im building LFS 9.0 and have reached chapter 6.7. When running make mrproper I get the output:

```
make: /bin/sh: Command not found
...(above repeated ~20 times)...
make: /bin/sh: Command not found
Makefile:649: arch//Makefile: no such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'arch//Makefile'. Stop.
```

I've tried rebooting, remounting the filesystem and chroting into the system as described in 6.2 and 6.4. I've also tried remaking the /bin/sh symlink both before and after the reboot. 
I think I followed the book correctly
Since restarting I ran the following commands

```
mount -v --bind /dev $LFS/dev
mount -vt devpts devpts $LFS/dev/pts -o gid=5,mode=620
mount -vt proc proc $LFS/procmount -vt sysfs sysfs $LFS/sys
mount -vt tmpfs tmpfs $LFS/run

chroot "$LFS" /tools/bin/env -i HOME=/root TERM="$TERM" PS1='(lfs chroot) \u:\w\$ ' PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin /tools/bin/bash --login +h

ln -sv /tools/bin/{bash,cat,chmod,dd,echo,ln,mkdir,pwd,rm,stty,touch} /bin
ln -sv /tools/bin/{env,install,perl,printf} /usr/bin
ln -sv /tools/lib/libgcc_s.so{,.1} /usr/lib
ln -sv /tools/lib/libstdc++.{a,so{,.6}} /usr/lib
ln -sv bash /bin/sh

under /sources/linux-5.2.8 ran
makr mrproper
```

Update:
After unlinking bash and sh then rerunning "ln -sv bash /bin/sh" I'm back to the original output. I ran "find /bin -type l -ls" to get the list of symlinks in .bin and it returned this for /bin/sh:

```
/bin/sh -> bash
```

Comment: What happens if you try to run `/bin/sh` (in the chroot)?

Comment: "sh: /bin/sh: No such file or directory"
I looked throuh the bin directory and found i mistypes "bash" as "basg" when making the link. Deleted basg and reran ln -sv bash /bin/sh. The make mrproper output is now "Too many levels of symbolic link"

Comment: `makr mrproper` wouldn't give this output either. Always **copy-paste** what you ran, never retype. If what you tell us is different from what you actually did, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mistyped bash when making the first round of symlinks. Fixed by unlinking bash and /bin/sh and rerunning "ln -sv /tools/bin/bash /bin" then "ln -sv bash /bin/sh"